# How to write Python scripts that work with Linux pipes?

Tags: python, linux

In `speaker.py`, I use `print` to output text to `STDOUT`:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("hello")
```

And in `listener.py`, I use `input` to read from `STDIN`:

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        break
    print(line)
```

I'm trying to connect these two scripts with a pipe:

`python speaker.py | python listener.py`

But `listner.py` output nothing.

What's wrong?

Comment: When standard output is a tty, it is line buffered. When it is something else, it is block buffered. Either flush the buffer explicitly, or re-open the standard output with line buffering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is wrong per se, but you bumped into buffering. Take out the `sleep` and you should see output pretty much immediately.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009 is nominally a Bash question, but applies to any Unix-type I/O, and explains the issues thoroughly.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to re-opening stdout as Andrea mentioned is to start up Python in unbuffered mode with the -u option:

```
python -u speaker.py | python -u listener.py
```

Comment: Great tip; just to complement it: strictly speaking, you don't need the _2nd_ `-u` _here_, because `-u` only relates to the standard _output_ streams (stdout, stderr). An alternative to `-u` is to set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable to a non-empty value - see https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u